# Performing Tool Validation in Python Toolbox?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcpy, python-toolbox, tool-validation

I'm trying to make sure there is no '-' in the output filename, and if there is, to set an error (circle with the red 'X') so that the tool can't be run, and have a tooltip that explains the issue.  I've tried a bunch of things, but from what I've read, it seems this should work:

```
if parameters[7].value:
            if parameters[7].value.value.count("-") > 0:
                parameters[7].setErrorMessage("Output cannot have a '-'." + \
                    "Please change the dash and rename the output after the tool has run")
            else:
                parameters[7].clearMessage()
        return
```

I'm not super clear on what is returned from the list of parameters.  The paramater type is "DEShapefile".  There is no error message being thrown when I use "--" as the filename.

Can someone see why it's not working for me?

Comment: You have .value.value in your second line, should that not be just .value?

Comment: That's what I thought at first, but it didn't work at all.  I even tried str(parameters[7].value).count().  No luck.  I got .value.value from here. Near the bottom:
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Customizing_tool_behavior_in_a_Python_toolbox/00150000002m000000/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I spoofed up a Python script of 1 parameter and wired it into toolbox and this is how I got it to check a FeatureClass input:

```
import arcpy

class ToolValidator(object):
  """Class for validating a tool's parameter values and controlling
  the behavior of the tool's dialog."""

  def __init__(self):
    """Setup arcpy and the list of tool parameters."""
    self.params = arcpy.GetParameterInfo()

  def initializeParameters(self):
    """Refine the properties of a tool's parameters.  This method is
    called when the tool is opened."""
    return

  def updateParameters(self):
    """Modify the values and properties of parameters before internal
    validation is performed.  This method is called whenever a parameter
    has been changed."""

    return

  def updateMessages(self):
    """Modify the messages created by internal validation for each tool
    parameter.  This method is called after internal validation."""
    self.params[0].clearMessage()
    if self.params[0].value is None:
        self.params[0].clearMessage()
    else:
        fc = str(self.params[0].value.value)
        if fc.count("-") > 0:
            self.params[0].setErrorMessage("Output cannot have a dash")
        else:
            self.params[0].clearMessage()
    return
```

Comment: I don't think you need to call clearMessage() twice.

Comment: Hmm... I'll try putting my code in updateMessages(), I had it in updateParameters().  It must be that any messages I am trying to show are being overwritten by the validating step.  I'll try it out first chance I get.  Thanks!