# How do you use the setErrorMessage(message:string) within the ToolValidator Class?

Tags: arcpy, tool-validation

The [Programming ToolValidor Class ArcGIS Help menu](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#/Programming_a_ToolValidator_class/00150000000v000000/) states that: the following method:
`setErrorMessage(message:string)`
"Marks the parameter as having an error (a red X) with the supplied message. Tools do not execute if any of the parameters have an error."
Does anyone have an example of the code working to make the red x appear?

Comment: Check out this answer: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/78591/34624 (if you haven't already tracked this down yourself)

Comment: Thank you that's a great response.  I wound up watching the free tutorial on esri's training titled "Creating Python Toolboxes Using ArcGIS 10.1".